# How to combine each and attr functions

Tags: jquery

Hey I am trying to loop through all the elements having the class foo and also not having the attr 'visibility' set to 'hidden'.

I have the following code which doesn't work.

The error comes from the `attr()` which isn't defined. How can I make this right ?

```
$('.foo').each( function() {
    if ($(this).attr('visibility') !== 'hidden') {
        $(this).hide();               
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.css()` instead of `.attr()`. **visibility** is a one property of css. you not directly call with attr or prop. That's have option in jquery is `.css()`

```
if ($(this).css('visibility') !== 'hidden') {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` and `.css()`, `'attr()'` does not return css/style properties.

```
$('.foo').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('visiblity') !== 'hidden'                 
}).hide();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pnagwatg/)**

`.filter()` - gets all visible (style : `visibility !== visible` elements.

---

Note: *`.hide()` alters css `display`  property and not `visibility`*. If you wish to alter `visibility` use `.css('visibility','hidden')` instead of `hide()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use prop instead of attr and remove the !==

```
$('.foo').each( function() {
                        if ($(this).prop('visibility') != 'hidden') {
                          $(this).hide();               
                      }
```